# Split function doesn't recognize 'x^'

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to use the Split function in java 
However I try to split and remove 'x' and '^'

this is a sample code and the system is printing "-x^3" and I don't know why?
I try to use \ in between but still no successes.

```
    String str = "-x^3";

    String[] s = str.split("x^");

    for (String a : s){

        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

I expect the output of s[0]to be "-" and s[1] to be 3, but the actual output is s[0] = "-x^3" without any change.

Comment: `String[] s = str.split("x\\^");`

Comment: `split` takes regex and in regex `^` is metacharacter. See more at https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: what should happen with `"-x3^4"` ?

Comment: I hope to get an arrey of arr[0]="-" arr[1]=3 arr[2]=4.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to enclose the regex in `[ ]`

[image]

Use as `String[] s = str.split("[x^]");`

Comment: That would split on either `x` OR `^`, not only on sequence of `x^`.

Comment: no, this would split `"axb"` in 2; `"ax^b"` in 3 strings (middle one empty)

Comment: I'm not trying to split only the sequence "x^" but "x" or "^".